# Unable to render table with TRs using Mustache.js

Tags: mustache

I have a template that has a section to render a list of items as a Table:

```
...
<table>
    <tbody>
    {{#arrProps}}
         <tr>
              <td><strong>{{Label}}</strong>:</td>
              <td>{{Description}}</td>
         </tr> 
    {{/arrProps}}
    </tbody>
</table>
...
```

When rendering it, it becomes (an empty row):

```
<table>
   <tbody>                        
     <tr>
       <td><strong></strong>:</td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>                         
   </tbody>
</table>
```

If I remove the `<table>` tags from the template, the Mustache renders a list of TRs without a problem with the correct data replaced.  But I need the `<table></table>` wrapper.

**Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you get this going?

Comment: Yes, I ended up wrapping the template with a SCRIPT tag. I don't know why, but works.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, the template should be surrounded by `<script id="yourID" type="x-tmpl-mustache">...</script>`. Not sure if id is required, probably not.